# How to use an AWX template when each host has a different SSH Key

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am trying to setup AWX. I have created a template and it works fine against an inventory with a single host in it.

Each of my hosts has a different ssh key for the Ansible user, this is to reduce the blast radius if a key was exposed and is a requirement for our security policy.

AWX only allows you to add a single credential of each type to a template, so I can't add a second machine credential to the Template.

**edit**
I believe the way to go is with Custom Credential Types.
I have created a custom credential type for each of my hosts, then created a new credential based on each of these credential types.
This is an example of one of my credential types

**Input Configuration**

```yaml
fields:
  - id: username
    type: string
    label: Username
  - id: my_ssh_key
    type: string
    label: Private Key
    format: ssh_private_key
    secret: true
    multiline: true
required:
  - username
  - my_ssh_key
```

**Injector configuration**

```yaml
file:
  template.my_key: '{{ my_ssh_key }}'
extra_vars:
  userlogin: '{{ username }}'
  my_ssh_key_file: '{{ tower.filename.my_key }}'
```

In my global Inventory **Variables**, I have the following

```yaml
---
ansible_private_key_file: "{{ my_ssh_key_file }}"
ansible_user: "{{ userlogin }}"
```

In templates I have removed all Credentials entries.

When I then run the Template, I get the following errors

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [192.168.100.172]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'remote_user' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'userlogin' is undefined. 'userlogin' is undefined. 'userlogin' is undefined. 'userlogin' is undefined"}
fatal: [192.168.100.180]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'remote_user' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'userlogin' is undefined. 'userlogin' is undefined. 'userlogin' is undefined. 'userlogin' is undefined"}
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.100.172            : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
192.168.100.180            : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If I hard code the username `ansible` in my Inventory Variables, then I get the error that the `my_ssh_key_file` variable is undefined.

Comment: I have not used awx before but can't you just set the ssh key as a hist variable ?

Comment: Yea, in Ansible you can use ansible_ssh_private_key_file=.... but  I don't know how to replicate that in AWX.

Comment: Set this variable in your inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my setup for a custom SSH credential for a host.

**Input configuration**

```
    fields:
  - id: username
    type: string
    label: Username
  - id: my_ssh_key
    type: string
    label: Private Key
    format: ssh_private_key
    secret: true
    multiline: true
required:
  - username
  - my_ssh_key
```

**Injector Configuration**

```
extra_vars:
  my_ssh_key_file: '{{tower.filename}}'
  userlogin: '{{username}}'
  userpass: 'null'
file:
  template: '{{my_ssh_key}}'
```

Nothing in global variables but my inventory looks like this

```
[server]
server1_ip_server ansible_host=1.2.3.4
[server:vars]
ansible_user=exampleuser
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_private_key_file="{{ my_ssh_key_file }}"
```

Playbook is pretty standard, just pick your the group/host and run tasks.